# Getting "No route matches" error even though I defined a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes, find

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m trying to write an AJAX method to invoke a method in my controller, but I’m getting a no-router error.  In my coffee script, I have this

```
updateAll = (arg) ->
  object = $('#user_object_object').val()
  day = $('#user_object_day').val()
  $.ajax
    url: "/find_by_user_object_and_day"
    type: 'GET'
    data: {day: day, object: object}
    success: (data) ->
      $('total').val(data)
    error: ->
      alert "Something went wrong"
```

and in my config/routes.rb I have this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user_objects do
    get :find_by_user_object_and_day, on: :collection 
  end
```

and then in my “./app/controllers/user_objects_controller.rb” I have this

```
def find_by_user_object_and_day
  Userobject.find_by_user_object_and_day(:params[user], :params[object], :params[day])
end
```

but when my AJAX method is invoked, this error is produced on the server …

```
F, [2016-02-05T15:52:29.916816 #12058] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/find_by_user_object_and_day"):
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are defining the route within the resources 'user_objects, the route will be available at /user_objects/find_by_user_object_and_day, not at /find_by_user_object_and_day.

If you want it to be able at root level /find_by_user_object_and_day then you also need to define the route at the root level as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/find_by_user_object_and_day', to: 'user_objects#find_by_user_object_and_day'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in your routes, which means you'll get a nested url / path:

```
resources :user_objects do
    get :find_by_user_object_and_day, on: :collection #-> url.com/users_objects/:user_object_id/find_by_user_object_and_day
end
```

Since you have to define the route explicitly in JS (it has no way to know which `:user_object_id` you wish to send your visitors), you'll have to change your `ajax#url` value to the following:

```
updateAll = (arg) ->
  user_object_id = $('#user_object').data("id") #-> however you define the id
  object         = $('#user_object_object').val()
  day            = $('#user_object_day').val()
  $.ajax
    url: "user_objects/" +  user_object_id + "/find_by_user_object_and_day"
```